# Mongoose custom type causes 500 internal server error in hapi / rest-hapi

Tags: javascript, mongoose, hapi.js

I am using Mongoose in a hapi server with rest-hapi.  I have defined a custom type in Mongoose, according to the documentation at http://mongoosejs.com/docs/customschematypes.html.  After encountering issues with my own custom type, I also tried the documentation's Int8 example.

With the custom type, an invalid value causes the hapi server to encounter an internal server error, rather than returning a 400 error response.  With the built-in string type, an invalid value results in the expected 400 error response.

I've looked at the implementation of the String type, and its cast function throws an error for an invalid value, just like the cast function in my custom type.  (Note the example has a comment that says to throw a CastError, but actually throws an Error.  I've tried it both ways, with the same result.)

**What do I need to do to make my custom type behave the same as the built-in types for invalid values?**

Here's a test model the demonstrates the issue:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(mongoose) {
  function Int8(key, options) {
    mongoose.SchemaType.call(this, key, options, 'Int8');
  }

  Int8.prototype = Object.create(mongoose.SchemaType.prototype);

  Int8.prototype.cast = function(val) {
    let _val = Number(val);
    if (isNaN(_val)) {
      throw new Error('Int8: ' + val + ' is not a number');
    }
    _val = Math.round(_val);
    if (_val < -0x80 || _val > 0x7F) {
      throw new Error('Int8: ' + val +
                      ' is outside of the range of valid 8-bit ints');
    }
    return _val;
  };

  mongoose.Schema.Types.Int8 = Int8;

  const modelName = 'test';
  const Types = mongoose.Schema.Types;

  const Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    string: {
      type: Types.String,
      required: true,
    },
    int8: {
      type: Types.Int8,
      required: true,
    },
  });

  Schema.statics = {
    collectionName: modelName,
    routeOptions: {},
  };

  return Schema;
};
```

Here's my test file:

```
'use strict';

const expect = require('chai').expect;
const merge = require('lodash/merge');

describe.only('/test', () => {
  describe('POST', () => {
    const requestDefaults = {
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/test',
      payload: {},
    };

    describe('invalid data', () => {
      it('should reject missing fields', () => {
        const request = merge({}, requestDefaults);

        return server.inject(request)
          .then(response => {
            expect(response)
              .to.be.an('object')
              .with.property('statusCode', 400);
          });
      });

      it('should reject invalid string', () => {
        const request = merge({}, requestDefaults, {
          payload: {
            string: 7,
            int8: 7,
          },
        });

        return server.inject(request)
          .then(response => {
            expect(response)
              .to.be.an('object')
              .with.property('statusCode', 400);
          });
      });

      it('should reject invalid int8', () => {
        const request = merge({}, requestDefaults, {
          payload: {
            string: 'hello',
            int8: 0xFF,
          },
        });

        return server.inject(request)
          .then(response => {
            expect(response)
              .to.be.an('object')
              .with.property('statusCode', 400);
          });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

And here's the test output (with the stacktrace trimmed):

```
[10:34:16.983] 39140 LOG      api/mongoose — Connecting to Database...:
[10:34:16.991] 39140 LOG      api/mongoose —    URI: `mongodb://127.0.0.1:9001/test`
[10:34:17.013] 39140 LOG      api — Initializing Server...


(node:39140) DeprecationWarning: `open()` is deprecated in mongoose >= 4.11.0, use `openUri()` instead, or set the `useMongoClient` option if using `connect()` or `createConnection()`. See http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#use-mongo-client
  /test
    POST
      invalid data
        ✓ should reject missing fields (95ms)
        ✓ should reject invalid string
[10:34:18.151] 39140 LOG      api/test/Create — params({}), query({}), payload({"string":"hello","int8":255})
[10:34:18.181] 39140 ERROR    ../../rest-hapi/utilities/handler-helper.js:464:23 api/test/Create — There was an error creating the resource.
[10:34:18.183] 39140 ERROR    ../../rest-hapi/utilities/error-helper.js:27:11 api/test/Create — MongooseError: 
[10:34:18.183] 39140 ERROR    ../../rest-hapi/utilities/error-helper.js:27:11 api/test/Create —     at ValidationError (/Users/chipmunk/git/magic-wand-api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/validation.js:27:11)
[10:34:18.183] 39140 ERROR    ../../rest-hapi/utilities/error-helper.js:27:11 api/test/Create —     at model.Document.invalidate (/Users/chipmunk/git/magic-wand-api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:1609:32)
[10:34:18.183] 39140 ERROR    ../../rest-hapi/utilities/error-helper.js:27:11 api/test/Create —     at model.Document.set (/Users/chipmunk/git/magic-wand-api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:758:10)
...
[10:34:18.186] 39140 ERROR    ../../rest-hapi/utilities/error-helper.js:60:11 api/test/Create — TypeError: Boom.serverTimeout is not a function
[10:34:18.186] 39140 ERROR    ../../rest-hapi/utilities/error-helper.js:60:11 api/test/Create —     at Object.formatResponse (/Users/chipmunk/git/magic-wand-api/node_modules/rest-hapi/utilities/error-helper.js:43:27)
...
        1) should reject invalid int8


  2 passing (1s)
  1 failing

  1) /test POST invalid data should reject invalid int8:

      AssertionError: expected { Object (raw, headers, ...) } to have property 'statusCode' of 400, but got 500
      + expected - actual

      -500
      +400

      at test/api/test.js:54:21
      at <anonymous>
      at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:208:7)



error Command failed with exit code 1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer to my question.

rest-hapi uses Joi to validate the document before passing it to Mongoose.  rest-hapi converts the Mongoose model to a Joi model by mapping the Mongoose types to corresponding Joi types.  Of course, it doesn't recognize my custom type, so it has Joi accept any value for that field.

So, for a field with the standard String type, rest-hapi rejects an invalid value in the initial validation step and returns a 400 error response.  For a field with a custom Mongoose type, rest-hapi accepts it in the initial validation step, but mongoose rejects it, and rest-hapi returns a 500 error response.

I haven't yet thought about how to resolve this difference in behavior.